# Is it possible to create a scrollable table in Google Sheets without freezing?

Tags: google-sheets, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I would like to know if it is possible to have a sheet in Google Sheets with like 35 rows and have a table with much more rows of data with a scroll in it.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining how this would look like. You mean to have some cells fixed and some others that can scroll? Or a table within a cell?

Comment: Basically, I would like to make a table like this but in Google Sheets: https://youtu.be/mpgB8XHnGxY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Table Chart.

1. Insert Chart
2. Select Table for the chart type
3. Set data range (for the one below `B120:B300,C120:C300,E120:E300,F120:F300`)

You'll have to have the data on a sheet somewhere and add each column separately as a data range. However it seems poorly supported. Last I checked it doesn't work very well on mobile. Also you can't format colors or font. It does allow sorting by column and alternating row color.
[image: Scroll-able table within a Google Sheet]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing exactly that. A good alternative is to [freeze the rows](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9060449) that you always would like to see. This makes the scrolling not apply to them.